# How do I calculate the vector of the point where two lines meet by equating coefficients?

Tags: vectors

I'm doing vector mechanics, and I came across this question:

OABC is a parallelogram.
P is the point where the diagonals OB and AC intersect.
The vectors a and c are equal to **OA** and **OC** respectively.
Prove that OA and OC bisect each other.

The answer in the book I'm reading shows that I needto get to P, starting from O. The two ways of doing this are:

OP= x(**OB**)= x(**c**+**a**) and OP= **a**+AP= **a**+ y(**-a**+**c**)

I then have to equate the two equations, giving me:

x(**c**+**a**)= **a**+ y(**-a**+**c**)

Then, I need to solve the equation, by equating the coefficients of a and c. From here, the book completely jumped a few steps, but I figured that I had to expand the equation and then factor a and c, giving me:

(x-1+y)**a**= (y-x)**c**

Then all I have to do supposedly is to equate the coefficients, to give me 
x=0.5.

This is what stumps me. In order to equate the coefficients, I need to know that **a** and **c** are equal, but how do I deduce that? Additionally, the answer in the book says y is also equal to x so is also 0.5, but I can't seem to reach that stage in the equation (in fact, y cancels out so I can't see where I can obtain its value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ are linearly independent (if OABC is a true parallelogram), so that your equality implies:
$$\begin{cases}
x-1+y=0,\\y-x=0.
\end{cases}$$
and you just have to solve this linear system.

Comment: That almost makes sense. Could you just explain why it is both sides of the equation are 0. And would this sort of thing apply to similar questions?

Comment: That is the definition of linear independence:the only  linear relation between independent vectors is the trivial relation (all coefficients equal to $0$).